# When using .load() to change a divs content do I need to re-include my scripts?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, include

Im using .load() to populate a div with new content but when I do I have to recall all my scripts in order to use them inside the new content I beieve this is whats causing my event handlers to fire twice.

Am I wrong about that? If not is there an alternative method?

```
    $('.user').click(function(){
    if ($section !== 'users'){
        $section = 'users';
        $('div#contentWrapper').fadeOut(0).empty();
        $('div#contentWrapper').load('pages/users.html').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
```

this is the code thats apparently firing twice.

```
    $('.addUser').click(function(){        
    $('.userPanel').fadeOut(0).empty();
    $('.userPanel').load('pages/addUser.html').fadeIn(500);
    });
```

I had initialy thought it was the fadeout that caused it so I set it to instant but that didnt resolve the issue. Another post on the site had recomended unbinding the click handler first but as I understand it this is a work around not a fix, and id rather fix the problem.

I am new to jquery and would really appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load elements dynamically, you need to use jQuery's `.on()` function to bind events to the elements that are loaded. You need to bind with `.on()` to an element that already exists in the DOM and usually the worst case scenario for that is the body element. If you be more specific than `body` you'll usually get improved performance.

For example, if you loaded a table row into a table and wanted to bind the click event on the new row, you'd use:

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: so in order to use any jquery inside of the div i loaded into a standard html page with headers that already include script calls to my scripts i have to bind each element i want to do something with? That seems a bit hinkey...

Comment: In order to bind any events to elements loaded dynamically you need to bind them with .on().

Comment: ok thanks for the quick reply guess im gonna have to do some restructuring.